# Find $int(\bar{B}(0, 1) \cup \bar{B}(2,1))$ and show it is open.

Tags: general-topology

Find $int(\bar{B}(0, 1) \cup \bar{B}(2,1))$ and show it is open.

Let $A = \bar{B}(0, 1) \cup \bar{B}(2,1)$, then $int(A) = ((A^c)^-)^c.$

Which I believe is $(A^c \cup \partial A)^c = B(0,1) \cup B(2,1)$

How do I prove $(A^c)^- = A^c \cup \partial A$

Answer (score 0):

The interior of $\overline{B(0,1)}\cup\overline{B(2,1)}$ is $B(0,1)\cup B(2,1)$. It is clear that$$B(0,1)\cup B(2,1)\subset\overline{B(0,1)}\cup\overline{B(2,1)}$$and that $B(0,1)\cup B(2,1)$ is an open set. Therefore, $B(0,1)\cup B(2,1)$ is a subset of the interior of $\overline{B(0,1)}\cup\overline{B(2,1)}$.

Now, suppose that $z\notin B(0,1)\cup B(2,1)$. Then every neighborhood of $z$ contains points $w$ such that $|w|>1$ or $|w-2|>1$ and therefore $z$ is not in the interior of $\overline{B(0,1)}\cup\overline{B(2,1)}$.